# Timing issue with image load?

Tags: javascript, image, onload, timing, easeljs

I have a draggable image class that displays an image as expected when it is the only object on the stage. But when I add other graphics objects the image is not visible until I mouseover where the image is located.

It seems like the stage needs an extra update when there are more graphics objects on the display list. Calling `tick()` or setting my update flag manually doesn’t solve the issue (presumably this happens too quickly).

I can hack around it by putting a counter in the tick function like
`if(update || ticks < 10)`. Clearly, this is not really a solution; the tick code shouldn’t have to check the counter every tick, forever.

Does anybody know the correct way?

You can see it here: http://eduk8r.org/bridge/. You’ll have to mouseover the image the first time, though. (The image is located to the left hand side of the bridge).

The relevant code is in `controller.js` and `DraggableImage.js`.

UPDATE: I had thought that reloading the page was sufficient to display the image but that only seems to happen locally.

Comment: Interesting issue! Basically you want to set the update flag after everything has loaded right?

Comment: I do call a handler when the onload event fires. The code is a little different than the easeljs drag-and-drop demo since I have it in a separate class and file. The thing that puzzles me is why it works when nothing else is on the stage but needs a subsequent update when other graphics are added. And I can't figure out how to call that subsequent update. Maybe a timeout? Shouldn't need to do that though.

Comment: did you already fix it? The image shows immediately now.

Comment: It's not showing for me in FF or Chrome. And reload isn't doing it either - I thought it was. I'm having to mouseover the image (left side of stage) for it to show. So, no, I haven't fixed it. I'm puzzled that you see the truck immediately - what browser are you using?